# Summation riddle duplicate values seen

Tags: python-3.x

- a list the output we get repeated values (3,20,7)
- how to remove the repeated values?
- is there a easier way to solve this?

```
    def riddle(x):
        list=[]
        i=0
        for i in range(0,len(x)):
            for j in range(i,len(x)):
                for k in range(j,len(x)):
                    if ((x[i]+x[j]+x[k]) ==30) and x[i]!=x[j]!=x[k]:
                        list.append((x[i],x[j],x[k]))
                        i = i+1
                        j= j+1
                        k = k+1
        return(list)

    print(riddle(x))
    x= [2,3,5,8,6,89,20,15,7]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def riddle(x):
    ls = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
                for k in range(j+1,len(x)):
                    u = x[i]+x[j]+x[k]
                    if u==30:
                        ls.append([x[i],x[j],x[k]])
    return ls

x = [2,3,5,8,6,89,20,15,7]
 riddle(x)
Out[58]: [[2, 8, 20], [3, 20, 7], [8, 15, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the name 'list' for a list as it's a keyword. I am going with list1 instead.

To get your answer, replace `return(list1)` with `return(set(list1))` to remove duplicates. If you want the answer as a list and not a set, do `return(list(set(list1)))`

(This will not be possible unless u rename your list to list1)

**Code:**

```py
def riddle(x):
    list1=[]
    i=0
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        for j in range(i,len(x)):
            for k in range(j,len(x)):
                if ((x[i]+x[j]+x[k]) ==30) and x[i]!=x[j]!=x[k]:
                    list1.append((x[i],x[j],x[k]))
                    i = i+1
                    j= j+1
                    k = k+1
    return(list(set(list1)))

x= [2,3,5,8,6,89,20,15,7]

print(riddle(x))
```

**Output**

```py
[(2, 8, 20), (8, 15, 7), (3, 20, 7)]
```

Comment: @Onyambu I just changed the 'return' part of the OP's code. Didn't check the other parts!